# Yii and TinyMCE with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I'm using TinyMCE in my form. Everything POSTS perfectly, until I enable ajax. When 'save' is clicked, the textarea 'content' is empty, but if I disable TinyMCE the ajax post shows up no problem. Any ideas?

Here's my code calling TinyMCE:

```
$tiny = new TinyMce();
    $tiny->buildTinyMce("textarea");
```

TinyMCE register functions:

```
public function buildTinyMce($selector="textarea"){
    $file = $this->getTinyMce().'/tinymce.min.js';
    $script = '
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "'.$selector.'",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
            "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor responsivefilemanager"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent",
        toolbar2: "| link unlink | image media | responsivefilemanager",

        external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title:"Media Manager",
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
    });
    ';
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($file);
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript("1",$script,CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
}
```

and finally my form

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'content');?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'content');?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'content');?>
</div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'type');?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Save' : 'Update',
        Yii::app()->createUrl('lesson/create'), array( 'dataType' => 'html', 'type' => 'post', 'update' => '.err-msg')
        ); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
<div class="err-msg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the content from editor to textarea before you submit the result using ajax.

See this [documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.save) for detail on save.

eg:

```
tinyMCE.get('TinyMCEId').save();
```